WinApi - Focus vs Active window
I struggle to understand the concept of the active window. According to the documentation the keyboard focus is strongly related to the active window:

The concept of keyboard focus is related to that of the active window.
The active window is the top-level window the user is currently
working with. The window with the keyboard focus is either the active
window, or a child window of the active window. To help the user
identify the active window, the system places it at the top of the Z
order and highlights its title bar (if it has one) and border.

Why the WinApi defines the concept of the active window separately ? There are functions like SetFocus/GetFocus and SetActiveWindow/GetActiveWindow. Please explain it based on some practical examples.

Here is a practical example that illustrates why activation and input focus are distinct concepts: How can I have a window that rejects activation but still receives pointer input?

Active window can be compound overlapped window with several controls (child windows). Only one of controls (e.g. EDIT) has the focus.
